# Why does Dajaxice and Dajax uses MEDIAL_URL?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-media, dajaxice

In Dajaxice's [installation documentation](http://docs.dajaxproject.com/dajaxice/installation.html), it says to set `DAJAXICE_MEDIA_PREFIX` in `settings.py`. Later that value is retrieved in the `urls.py`.

In Dajax's [installation documentation](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax/wiki/installation) (which is 2 years old), it says to load the *static* file like this:

```
<script src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/js/prototype.dajax.core.js.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Why is it using `MEDIA_URL`? Shouldn't it be using `STATIC_URL` since `js`, `css`, and `img` files should be `STATIC`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, their docs are out-of-date for Django > 1.3 I believe.  Just replace `MEDIA_URL` with `STATIC_URL` as you've already mentioned, e.g.,

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='{{STATIC_URL}}js/dajaxice.core.js' 
  charset='utf-8'></script>
```

Comment: Oh wait, I thought you could supply your own version of jQuery with Dajax? I just added it by doing `<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>` above the `<script>` for `jquery.dajax.core.js`. Does that not work?

Comment: I am pretty sure dajax bundles its own versions of the frameworks, see https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax/wiki for the versions it supports.  You'd probably end up loading multiple versions of whatever js framework you go with. jQuery's [noConflict mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page) would still allow you to use the latest jQuery though.

Comment: If you look at `jquery.dajax.core.js` it's simply a wrapper for jQuery. But where is the actual jQuery supplied by Dajax??

Comment: Ahah, you're right.  Always go to the source.  I think the version requirements are just the most recent "tested" version of the js framework that works.  I've updated the answer, thanks for the pointer.