# How to import dajaxice?

Tags: django, dajaxice, dajax, django-static

I'm a nooby to django and I tried many hours to get a simple example of dajaxice running, but I don't seem to find the right way to look for the files.

I did and redid [installation](http://django-dajaxice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) and tried to find answers in the numerous similar questions on stackoverflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519243/dajaxice-javascript-core-file-not-getting-parsed) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083334/why-does-dajaxice-and-dajax-uses-medial-url).

I put `{% dajaxice_js_import %}` in the header of `myapp_index.html` which prints out as:

```
<script src="/static/dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js"
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

but it cannot find this file:

> ImproperlyConfigured: The storage backend of the staticfiles finder  doesn't have a valid location.

And the get fails:

```
GET /static/dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Strangely enough dajax loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="{% static  /static/dajax/jquery.dajax.core.js" %}"></script>
```

Here's my folder structure:

```
myproject  
----manage.py  
----myproject  
--------settings.py  
--------urls.py  
----myapp  
--------ajax.py  
--------urls.py  
--------templates  
------------myapp_index.html
```

I also haven't really understood why we need two `urls.py` files, but somehow it seems to access `myapp_index.html` if I put

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
```

and then

```
url(r'^$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'myapp_index.html'}),
```

in `myapp`'s url patterns.

I also tried uncountable filenames in

```
python manage.py findstatic dajaxice.core.js
```

but somehow it doesn't find dajaxice, even though dajaxice is installed and accepted in the settings.py file among the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Also `python manage.py collectstatic` fails for the same reason, but if I understood correctly, I don't event have to make it run as long as I'm on a development server.

I guess I have some basic misunderstanding of the underlying structure. :(

I'm using the prepacked latest ubuntu packages:

```
django: 1.4.5, 
dajaxice: 0.5.5
```

Thanks in advance for any hint!

here is the template file:

```
{% load static %}
{% load dajaxice_templatetags %}

<html>
  <head>
    <title>My base template</title>
    {% dajaxice_js_import %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "/static/dajax/jquery.dajax.core.js" %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function my_js_callback(data){
alert(data.message);
}
Dajax;
Dajaxice;
  </script>
 </head>
...
 <button      onclick="Dajaxice.myproject.myapp.sayhello(my_js_callback);">Click here!</button>
```

I get no Django error, the page shows, but I get this in Firebug:

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error -  http://localhost:8000/static/dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js"
```

and this:

```
ReferenceError: Dajaxice is not defined
Dajaxice;
```

Comment: Please paste the output of `./manage.py collectstatic --noinput`.

Comment: Also, check that you have `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py`, launch [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/), open `Console` tab and reload your page. You should see something like Django error page with detailed information about the error in Firebug console log.

Comment: I edited my original question to include what you asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you've messed up your urls.conf. It should contain something like:

```
url(dajaxice_config.dajaxice_url, include('dajaxice.urls')),
```

Does it?

Also, the `STATICFILES_FINDERS` section of your `settings.py` file should include:

```
 'dajaxice.finders.DajaxiceFinder',
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! My STATICFILES_FINDERS had the third line (DefaultStorageFinder) uncommented, but I tried both and it doesn't make a difference, I tried commented and uncommented. Any other idea what I could check?

Comment: Hi! @kmgrds, please paste the output of `./manage.py collectstatic --noinput`.

Comment: Too long for the comment: hope this tail is enough: 
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 424, in render
    raise e
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'dajaxice-endpoint' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: Oh, it seems that you've messed up your `urls.conf`. It should contain something like `url(dajaxice_config.dajaxice_url, include('dajaxice.urls')),`. Does it?

Comment: Thanks so much! That was it! Actually, I had the line in my urls.py file in my app, but I didn't have it in my urls.py file of the project. I still haven't quite grasped this distinction. Thanks again for this quick help!

Comment: @Kmgrds, you're welcome! Have a nice day! And I'm going to bed now. :))